Read metaplex metadata in rust & anchor
can someone tell me where can i find an example to decode metadata in rust & anchor ?
i was using Metadata::from_account_info, but this is no available anymore in recent mpl_token_metadata versions, i tried with Metadata = Metadata::from_bytes(&ctx.accounts.pda_metadata.to_account_info().data).unwrap() but it's not working since ctx.accounts.pda_metadata.to_account_info().data is not  &[u8] but &Rc<RefCell<&mut [u8]>>
may be someone can tell me how to go from &Rc<RefCell<&mut [u8]>> to &[u8]  ?

With Anchor since account data is deserialized with the instruction call
let metadata = ctx.accounts.metadata_accounts
// yields https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/mpl_token_metadata/accounts/struct.Metadata.html#fields

If you have an AccountInfo, you can also do the deserialization on its data.
use mpl_token_metadata::accounts::Metadata as MPLMetadata;

let data = ctx.accounts.mtadata_accpunt.data.try_borrow_mut().unwrap();
let metadata_acc = MPLMetadata::deserialize(&mut data.as_ref());

Note: this assumes that you have confirmed that the account is a metadata account as the unwrap() will cause the program to panic if the data is something else.

thank you ! i'm trying the 2nd option, but i think it misses something ? i have this error now : no field primary_sale_happened on type std::result::Result<mpl_token_metadata::accounts::Metadata, std::io::Error>, any idea ?

Updated. Is this still occurring?

i have added a "?" like this : deserialize(&mut data.as_ref())?; and it works well, thank you, you gave me the right path !
